# Is there a more appropriate way to say "moved A below B"?

Tags: grammar, sentence

Given a flat surface and two objects `A` and `B`

> **After the guy moved `A` below `B`**.

Is there a better way to say it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: let's say two movable buttons on an `HTML` WebAplication, he moved button B below button A

Comment: I think I just answered my own question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative is:

- The guy placed A under B.

Comment: thanks for helping me. The `under` in this case could represent both 2D and 3D, right? or underneath would be more suitable to a 3D example?

Comment: @Calne: Either should be fine, Calne :)

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

> He placed A beneath B.

I think this works particularly well in a 2D context, and I understand that that is the nature of your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for helping. So `beneath` is as more "polite"/complex way for 2D as `underneath` is for a 3D context?.

Comment: You often hear beneath used in a 2D context (i.e. on a sheet of paper, or on a webpage). Underneath works for both I think.